# how can you display data from three related tables in django?

Tags: django

I'm new to django and I'm having trouble displaying related data from three related databases in a table. I hope you can help me.

Models.py

```
class recursos (models.Model):
gruporecurso= models.CharField (max_length=50, choices=TIPORECURSO, default=TIPODEFAULT)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
estado_disponible =models.BooleanField(default= True)
inventario = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank= True, null=True)
observacion = models.TextField(blank= True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.descripcion
    
class remito (models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField()
    hora = models.TimeField()
    responsable =  models. ForeignKey(personas, null=True, blank= True, verbose_name='Responsable',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area_pedido =  models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Área del pedido')
    operador =  models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=OPERADOR,verbose_name='Entregado por')
    lugardeuso =  models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name='Lugar uso')
    observacion =  models.TextField(blank= True, null=True)

    

class detalle_remito (models.Model):
    id_remito = models.ForeignKey(remito, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_recurso = models.ForeignKey(recursos, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return f' {self.id_recurso.descripcion}'
```

Views.py

```
def home (request):

remitos= remito.objects.all()
recursolist= detalle_remito.objects.all()
page= request.GET.get('page',1)
try:
    paginator = Paginator(remitos,5)
    remitos=paginator.page(page)
except:
    raise Http404

return render(request,"RemitoTicapp/home.html",{'entity': remitos ,'recursolist':recursolist,'paginator': paginator})
```

home.html

```
    {% extends "RemitoTicapp/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

   <!-- Heading 
   <section class="page-section clearfix">
    <div class="container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
   -->


<!-- Message -->
<section class="page-section cta">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
       <!--<div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto"> -->
        <div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
          <h2 class="section-heading mb-2">
            <span class="section-heading-upper">Sistema de Gestión de pedidos</span>
            <span class="section-heading-lower"> Elementos cedidos</span>
          </h2>
          <!--<p class="mb-0"> --> 
            <table class="table table-striped" bg  white>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Fecha entrega</th>
                      <th scope="col">Responsable</th>
                      <th scope="col">Area Pedido</th>
                      <th scope="col">Lugar de uso</th>
                      <th scope="col">Recurso / cantidad</th>
                      <th scope="col">Operador</th>
                      <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {% for remito in entity %}
                      <tr>
                          <td scope="row">{{ remito.fecha }}</td>
                          <td>{{ remito.responsable }}</td>
                          <td>{{ remito.area_pedido }}</td>
                          <td>{{ remito.lugardeuso }}</td>
                          <td> {% for recurso in recursolis %}
                                  {% if recurso.id_remito == remito.pk %}
                                     <li>{{ recurso.id_recurso.descripcion }} {{recurso.cantidad}}</li>

                                  {% endif %}
                              {% endfor %}
                          </td>
                          <td>{{ remito.operador }}</td>
                          <td>{{ remito.observacion }}</td>
                      </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
          </table>
           <div>
            {% include 'RemitoTicapp/paginator.html' %}
           </div>   
         <!-- </p> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</section>

{% endblock%}
```

We should show the data of Remito with the resources of detalle_remito with the description of each one of them from the recursos table.
From already thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have {% for recurso in recursolis %}, you could instead write {% for recurso in remito.detalle_remito_set.all %} and remove the if statement - it will loop through the detalle_remito objects that are connected to the recurso object

Answer (score 1):

Django will make the reverse foreign key relation accessible with the related model's name followed by a [`_set`-suffix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), exposing an instance of [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager).

```html
{% for detalle_remito in remito.detalle_remito_set.all %}
    {{ detalle_remito.id_recurso.descripcion }}
{% endfor %}
```

No need to gather addional data for that in your view.